# Git push returning error and not prompting for password

Tags: git, github

I followed the first steps after creating a repository in github, but when I got to the line:
    `git push -u origin master` it fails with this error:

```
user$ git push -u origin master
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/thestranger/cfinder.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I have remote added the correct origin url and I have git 1.7.10. The weird thing is that it is not prompting me for a username or password at all so I don't know what it's trying to use to access the repository on github. Does anyone know why it wouldn't prompt me for a password?

To clarify, the steps I followed were the ones github showed me after immediately creating the repository:

```
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/thestranger/cfinder.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: which OS? Do you have a SSH agent installed?

Comment: Mac OS X and I think so.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue on Mac OS X

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might try changing the URL to use SSH instead of HTTPS. In the root of your repo:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:thestranger/cfinder.git
```

This will require that you have a public key registered on your GitHub account.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I'm still wondering what the problem was though.

Comment: I'm not sure either. I've always used HTTPS for read-only access and SSH for read-write.

Answer (score 3):

https should be supported, but you need  git 1.7.10+

Answer (score 2):

In `git 1.7.1`, one can change the remote from:

```
https://github.com/username/project.git
```

to

```
https://username@github.com/username/project.git
```

That way, it definitely prompts for password.